# How this particular url rewrite can be done

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I have a site where both of the following URLs go to same page.

```
www.mydomain.com/pd/Children_Products/Toys/1/
www.mydomain.com/pd/Children_Products/Toys_/1/
```

First URL has `Toys`, 2nd has `Toys_`.

This is not good for search engines. I want that when second URL is visited, either return a 404 not found page, or simply redirect to the first URL.

I am not looking for solution to this particular url but also all such instances where this happens in my site for different directories.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more details about your setup. Do you use Apache HTTPD? Do your pages have some kind of code in them, like PHP?

You could take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which can be configured using regular expressions that would match any `_` in the URL. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)_/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R]
```

Comment: yes my pages are using php codes. Content is retrieved from php script. I dont know about Apache HTTPD. I host my site with a web hosting provider.